# Best use of new express card on Windows

Tags: windows, performance, virtualization, ssd, expresscard

I just bought a 48GB SSD express card for my laptop and I am trying to decide how best to use it.

I will be running some sort of virtualization (prob VirtualBox) to test / learn Windows Server administration.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.
I have 4GB of RAM and a 7200 RPM SATA hard disk.
The express card will read at 115MB/s and write at 65MB/s.

So how best to use this new disk? Readyboost, relocate pagefile, store VM disks, mix / match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could make it your boot drive, I'd say clone your OS onto it and use the internal drive for everything else.  :-)

Otherwise, put a pagefile on it if Win 7 will let you, and VM disks would also go well there.  I don't think ReadyBoost would provide a significant benefit on that system.

Comment: Well, my current c: drive is larger than my SSD :-( ... I might just do some testing to see what works best, but I like your suggestion. Thanks!